Why is an operator unitary if and only if its matrix representation is unitary?
I am currently reading Nielsen & Chuang's "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information". In it, for an operator (= a linear function) $f\colon V \to W$, the linear operator $f^\dagger$ is defined as the operator for which
$$
(f^\dagger(|w\rangle ), |v\rangle ) = (|w\rangle , f(|v\rangle ))
$$
holds for all $v\in V$, $w\in W$ with $(\cdot, \cdot)$ the inner product. Then a unitary operator is an operator for which $f^\dagger f = I$.
Later on they say "It is easily checked that an operator is unitary if and only if each of its matrix representations is unitary". I tried to come up with something for a while now, but I really don't understand how this is checked (especially not easily). Has anyone been there and found that out?
I include some screenshots on how the matrix representation is defined in the book (p. 63+):


Edit: the input and output bases for the matrix representation have to be orthonormal bases

The adjoint operator goes in the reverse direction $f^\dagger : W \rightarrow V$. In your notations the defining equality should be
$$
(f^\dagger(|w\rangle ), |v\rangle ) = (|w\rangle , f(|v\rangle )),  
$$
for $v \in V, w \in W$.
As for the unitary equivalence, you need to prove two things:

The matrix representation of a composition $AB$ of two operators $A: V \rightarrow W, B: W \rightarrow X$ equals to the product of matrix representations of $A$ and $B$.
The matrix representation of $f^\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose of the matrix representation of $f$.

Then the equality $ff^\dagger=I$ simply translates to the same equality but for the corresponding matrices.

Thank you very much for your answer! Took me a while now and it certainly didn't happen "easily", but you pointed me to the right direction and I was able to prove it now :)

The statement "an operator is unitary if and only if each of its matrix representations is unitary", when taken at face value is wrong. To see this take, for example, the operator $f:\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb C^2$, $f(x,y):=(x,-y)$ (i.e., $f\;\widehat=\;\sigma_z$) and choose the basis $B:=\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$. The corresponding matrix representation is readily verified to be
$$
f_B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2 \\0&-1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
which is obviously not unitary. The crucial missing assumption is that the basis has to be orthonormal to encode unitarity:

Theorem. Given finite-dimensional inner product spaces $V,W$ and a linear map $f:V\to W$ the following statements are equivalent.

$f$ is unitary, that is, $\langle f(x),f(y)\rangle_W=\langle x,y\rangle_V$ for all $x,y\in V$
For all orthonormal bases $B:=\{v_j\}_j$ of $V$ and $B':=\{w_k\}_k$ of $W$ the corresponding matrix representation $f_{BB'}$ is unitary
There exist orthonormal bases $B:=\{v_j\}_j$ of $V$ and $B':=\{w_k\}_k$ of $W$ such that the corresponding matrix representation $f_{BB'}$ is unitary


What is going on here mathematically is that change-of-basis matrices are invertible, and just invertibility does not respect unitarity. More precisely, if $U$ is a unitary matrix and $S$ is invertible (but not unitary), then $SUS^{-1}$—which is $U$ in the basis encoded by $S$—is in general not unitary anymore because $S^{-1}S^\dagger\neq{\bf1}$.
So for our statement to hold we need the change-of-basis matrix itself to be unitary, which is equivalent to its columns forming an orthonormal basis. So for two orthonormal bases—encoded in unitary matrices $U_V,U_W$—it is now easy to check that a given matrix $U$ is unitary if and only if $U_VUU_W^\dagger$ is unitary.

Thank you for your answer! And yes, you're right, the basis has to be orthonormal.
